# Localizing common strings like "copy", "cancel" or "File"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization

First of all: I do not want to know how to localize them myself, that is what i am already doing

However, i am right now trying to find a way to get access to those common strings that can be found in eg. a textbox context menu in XAML

thus here is my Question:
Is there some resource one can utilize in XAML to localize common strings or do i really have to re-do every "Cut", "Copy", "Paste", ... localization for each project myself?

Comment: You will need some third-party tool for this. Localization tools usually refer to this as **translation memory**. It would be in the feature set of more or less any localization tool.